# Can't login properly with requests-python

Tags: python, authentication, automation

i'm new here so Hi everyone. I'm quite noob in programming so sorry if this it is kind of basic and forgive my english :s
What i'm trying to do is to login in a website with python only with requests, i only allowed to do it by console. Then i would like to recopile some information but that is not the point of this thread. 
So far i've tried this with no much results:

```
import requests

payload = {
"CT_Main_0$txtUsername": "lcdtmab@mail.com", 
"CT_Main_0$txtPassword": "15948asd", 
"__EVENTVALIDATION": "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"
}
s = requests.Session()
url = "http://www.agweb.com/members/login/?b=y"
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
r.text
```

You can use those username and psw because I created them only for try.

Here is some of the output of r.text (don't let me put all, really long):

```
'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n<head id="head"><link rel="canonical" href="http://www.agweb.com/members/login/" /><meta property="og:title" content="Login | Agweb.com" /><meta property="og:type" content="website" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.agweb.com/members/login/?b=y" /><meta property="og:description" content="" /><meta property=\'og:site_name\' content=\'AgWeb - The Home Page of Agriculture\'/> \n<meta property=\'og:locale\' content=\'en_US\' />  <title>\r\n\tLogin | Agweb.com\r\n</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow" />\r\n\r\n\t<!-- Set viewport to device default -->\r\n\t<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" /><meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><link rel="icon" href="/cms/images/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />\r\n<script type="text/javascript"> \r\nvar _gaq = _gaq || [];\r\n_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-3975964-1\']); \r\n_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']); \r\n_gaq.push([\'_trackPageLoadTime\']); \r\n\r\n(function() {   var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); \r\nga.type = \'text/javascript\'; \r\nga.async = true;   \r\nga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\'; \r\nvar s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\r\n })();\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="application/ld+json">\r\n{\r\n "@context": "http://schema.org",\r\n "@type": "WebPage",\r\n "headline": "Members - Login",\r\n "url": "http://www.agweb.com/members/login/",\r\n "thumbnailUrl": "",\r\n "dateCreated": "2014-09-10T11:35:38Z",\r\n "articleSection": "Members",\r\n "creator": ["agweb.com"],\r\n "keywords": []\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

But when i login from my browser the html looks super different.
I also tried to do

```
r = s.get("http://discussions.agweb.com/index.php")
```

Which is the page that came after login in my browser, but the output of r.text in this case was something like this (which again doesn't match):

```
'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">\r\n<script>\r\n(function(){function getSessionCookies(){var cookieArray=new Array();var cName=/^\\s?incap_ses_/;var c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){var key=c[i].substr(0,c[i].indexOf("="));var value=c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=")+1,c[i].length);if(cName.test(key)){cookieArray[cookieArray.length]=value}}return cookieArray}function setIncapCookie(vArray){var res;try{var cookies=getSessionCookies();var digests=new Array(cookies.length);for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){digests[i]=simpleDigest((vArray)+cookies[i])}res=vArray+",digest="+(digests.join())}catch(e){res=vArray+",digest="+(encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))}createCookie("___utmvc",res,20)}function simpleDigest(mystr){var res=0;for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){res+=mystr.charCodeAt(i)}return res}function createCookie(name,value,seconds){var expires="";if(seconds){var date=new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));var expires="; expires="+date.toGMTString()}document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"}function test(o){var res="";var vArray=new Array();for(var j=0;j<o.length;j++){var test=o[j][0];switch(o[j][1]){case"exists":try{if(typeof(eval(test))!="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=true")}else{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=false")}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=false")}break;case"value":try{try{res=eval(test);if(typeof(res)==="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=undefined")}else if(res===null){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=null")}else{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+res.toString())}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=cannot evaluate");break}break}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}case"plugin_extentions":try{var extentions=[];try{i=extentions.indexOf("i")}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=indexOf is not a function");break}try{var num=navigator.plugins.length;if(num==0||num==null){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=no plugins");break}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=cannot evaluate");break}for(var i=0;i<navigator.plugins.length;i++){if(typeof(navigator.plugins[i])=="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=plugins[i] is undefined");break}var filename=navigator.plugins[i].filename;var ext="no extention";if(typeof(filename)=="undefined"){ext="filename is undefined"}else if(filename.split(".").length>1){ext=filename.split(\'.\').pop()}if(extentions.indexOf(ext)<0){extentions.push(ext)}}for(i=0;i<extentions.length;i++){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext="+extentions[i])}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext="+e)}break}}vArray=vArray.join();return vArray}var o=[["navigator","exists"],["navigator.vendor","value"],["navigator.appName","value"],["navigator.plugins.length==0","value"],["navigator.platform","value"],["navigator.webdriver","value"],["platform","plugin_extentions"],["ActiveXObject","exists"],["webkitURL","exists"],["_phantom","exists"],["callPhantom","exists"],["chrome","exists"],["yandex","exists"],["opera","exists"],["opr","exists"],["safari","exists"],["awesomium","exists"],["puffinDevice","exists"],["__nightmare","exists"],["_Selenium_IDE_Recorder","exists"],["document.__webdriver_script_fn","exists"],["document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_","exists"],["process.version","exists"],["navigator.cpuClass","exists"],["navigator.oscpu","exists"],["navigator.connection","exists"],["window.outerWidth==0","value"],["window.outerHeight==0","value"],["window.WebGLRenderingContext","exists"],["document.documentMode","value"],["eval.toString().length","value"]];try{setIncapCookie(test(o));document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+Math.random()}catch(e){img=document.createElement("img");img.src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+e}})();\r\n</script>\r\n<script>\r\n(function() { \r\nvar z="";var b="7472797B766172207868723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528293B766172207374617475733D227374617274223B7661722074696D696E673D6E65772041727261792833293B77696E646F772E6F6E756E6C6F61643D66756E6374696F6E28297B74696D696E675B325D3D22723A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E74287374617475732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B69662877696E646F772E584D4C4874747052657175657374297B7868723D6E657720584D4C48747470526571756573747D656C73657B7868723D6E657720416374697665584F626A65637428224D6963726F736F66742E584D4C4854545022297D7868722E6F6E726561647973746174656368616E67653D66756E6374696F6E28297B737769746368287868722E72656164795374617465297B6361736520303A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374206E6F7420696E697469616C697A656420223B627265616B3B6361736520313A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2073657276657220636F6E6E656374696F6E2065737461626C6973686564223B627265616B3B6361736520323A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374207265636569766564223B627265616B3B6361736520333A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2070726F63657373696E672072657175657374223B627265616B3B6361736520343A7374617475733D22636F6D706C657465223B74696D696E675B315D3D22633A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B6966287868722E7374617475733D3D323030297B706172656E742E6C6F636174696F6E2E72656C6F616428297D627265616B7D7D3B74696D696E675B305D3D22733A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B7868722E6F70656E2822474554222C222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F535748414E45444C3D3138323634303032333136323231323137312C363431363632303333353632363938363136372C363432323235373630333133353433383334342C353733383537222C66616C7365293B7868722E73656E64286E756C6C297D63617463682863297B7374617475732B3D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B2220696E6361705F6578633A20222B633B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E74287374617475732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval(\'String.fromCharCode(\'+z+\')\'));})();\r\n</script></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>\r\n</body></html>'
```

That's my main problem i think it doesn't login at all and i don't know what is the issue. If someone could help me I really apreciate it.

Comment: I tried the website you want to login.  It is a very complicated login process and not easy to solve it.  You have to set proper headers, catch the right cookies, decode the verification string.  To be honest, I think this is already beyond your ability, and also mine.

Comment: Well, thanks for your honesty and for your time to check the page. Really apreciate it.

Comment: use selenium to mimic a whole browser instead of using requests

Comment: Hi thanks for comment, but in the description i've mentioned that i can't use selenium or webdriver, i only have to use a terminal

Comment: you can try phantomjs it will try to mimic the browser do without browser. the problem with requests it doesn't render javascript (that I know of), while what you need is to mimic how browser operate.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions but i've been reading about phantomjs and it needs from selenium so i think it couldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone is seeing this i found a solution and it was to give to the post method all of the information that my browser was giving to the site, kind of a simulation, you can get this info from (in mozilla) the option developer, and then network, when you login the site, look for the POST and then look the header info and the params and copy and paste into your values this is what i've got:

```
import requests
payload = {


    "__EVENTTARGET": "",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
    "__LASTFOCUS": "",
    "hdnSubDirectory=": "",
    "CT_Header_1$drpBrandId": "",
    "CT_Header_1$ctl00$txtSearch": "",
    "CT_TopNavigation_0$hdnBrandId": "",
    "CT_Main_0$txtUsername": "lcdtmab@mail.com" ,
    "CT_Main_0$txtPassword": "15948asd" ,
    "CT_Main_0$btnLogin": "Login" ,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "3989C74E" ,
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": "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" ,
    "__VIEWSTATE": "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"

}

headers = {

    "Host": "www.agweb.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": ",en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": ",gzip, deflate",
    "Referer": "http://www.agweb.com/members/login/?b=y",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=42m4w0tdk030u3cdnzlkuhzi; ASP_NET_SessionId=42m4w0tdk030u3cdnzlkuhzi; NadO96yv2ZoB3UyVoxgdf1l6iTBOYPurmNtmEApre4c%3D=; RtjcAfel6cYTmfS4zKEmdfyAy%2F5dmTx3wfxCrAV7NoE%3D=; visid_incap_96445=h1wbHyUZSwqCD2eMly6Yf/875FgAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD2xzqMUrot46yyF9WerjF2; incap_ses_298_96445=XNgtVGCaTgcm+613qLYiBP875FgAAAAAasH2gAS6npgJtIPVo95vsA==",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",

}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("http://www.agweb.com/members/login/?b=y", headers=headers)
url = "http://www.agweb.com/members/login/?b=y"

r = s.post(url, headers=headers,data=payload)
```